# How to customise the permission dialog in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, getusermedia

I want to customize the permission dialog which is used to ask for permission from users like in the image. What I meant for customization is like right now it's on the top left corner in the browser. But I want it in the middle of the page with some changes in font and background color changed. Will I able to do that? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I regret to inform you, You Can't Do That™. For security reasons the browsers give you no control over appearance and behavior of those permission dialogs.

Because cybercreeps.